# Put the cross on the top right page instead of the left

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

how can I put the cross on the top right side of my page? For now it appears on the left side.

```
.close {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.close:focus,
.close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
.close:active {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
}
.close::before,
.close::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: currentColor;
}
.close::before {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.close::after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

My snipped code :https://jsfiddle.net/Lcqy3srg/3/

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: Use position: absolute and right: 0 for starters.

Comment: @MohamedGhulam I tried but it says 'your post is mostly code'

Comment: @ChrisG I've already tried it not working either.

Comment: Weird, because it works on the spot: https://jsfiddle.net/5rpyozdw/ Also, "not working" is a useless problem description.

Comment: @MosiaThabo Yes, so? Did you not see my previous comment and OP's reply?

Comment: This is a very poor question. In your `.close` style you didn't define the position. yet you want it to be positioned out of nowhere without telling it to.

Comment: @Zokulko learn more about absolute positioning here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjsrpHhnt_3AhUQEcAKHY-uA3gQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Fposition&usg=AOvVaw2FFc5t6zxL7lglQmPh88Yc

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/Lcqy3srg/3/, I've put all my code

Answer (score 0):

## float

Use `float: right` on `.close`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```css
/*Button to quit the form*/

.close {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  float: right;
}

.close:focus,
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}

.close:active {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
}


/* tines of the X */

.close::before,
.close::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.close::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.close::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

## position

Using `position: absolute` and `right: 0px` will result in the same effect. It however requires more work, and might not work in many cases where you need to use a position other than `absolute`. (for example in this case, it gives a scroll bar because it was intended to use `relative`)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
/*Button to quit the form*/

.close {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute; /*Changed to absolute*/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  right: 0px;
}

.close:focus,
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}

.close:active {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
}


/* tines of the X */

.close::before,
.close::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.close::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.close::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="close" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you simply  can add div "content" as parent of div "close"

```
 .content {

    position:absolute ;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Code screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Already try it but not working either:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lcqy3srg/3/